# Flexdashboard - Modularise rCharts code

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts, flexdashboard

I'm trying to break some code for a dashboard down into modules.  I'm having trouble with this `rCharts` code.  I can run it as an app, but ideally I want to split it into `UI` and `server` functions so I can keep them in a package.

The code below shows the working code in an app and the broken code as a module.  Could anyone point out what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks

````
---
title: "Example"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
X <- data.frame(Var1 = rep(1:10, 3),
                Var2 = rep(c("control", "treatment1", "treatment2"), each = 10),
                Freq = abs(rnorm(30, 0, 1))
)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Broken Code as Module

```{r}
ui2 = function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)

  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1", height = "100%"),
            showOutput(ns("histogram"), "nvd3"))
}

server2 = function(input, output, session) {
      output$histogram <- renderChart2({
        n2 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Var1, group = 'Var2', data = X, type = 'multiBarChart')
        n2$set(width = session$clientData$output_plot1_width)
        n2
      })
}

ui2("example")
callModule(server2, "example")
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Working Code as App

```{r}
shinyApp(
  ui = mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot2", height = "100%"),
        showOutput("histogram", "nvd3")
      ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
      output$histogram <- renderChart2({
        n2 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Var1, group = 'Var2', data = X, type = 'multiBarChart')
        n2$set(width = session$clientData$output_plot2_width)
        n2
      })
    }
)
```

### Template

```{r}

```
````

---

**Update in response to @HubertL's reply**

The below code, when appended to the main body above illustrates the way `flexdashboard` can run `shiny` apps as standalone functions (note the `runtime: shiny` in the header).

The stand alone functions here can be stored in a library to be called at will, and do not need to be wrapped by `shinyApp`.

To clarify, the question I'm asking is how CAN I accomplish calling the `rCharts` plot as a series of standalone UI and server functions, as I can do with normal `plots`, or if this isn't possible, why not?

````
Stand Alone Example
======================================================================

Inputs{.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
## UI for choosing species
iris_plotUI = function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)

  # User choices for line
  list_species = list(
    "Setosa" = "setosa",
    "Versicolor" = "versicolor",
    "Virginica" = "virginica"
  )

  flowLayout(
    # input: Tube line selection
    selectInput(
      ns("type"),
      label = h3("Select Species:"),
      choices = list_species,
      selected = "setosa"
    )
  )
}

# server module
iris_plot = function(input, output, session) {
  library(MASS)
  library(data.table)

  dt = data.table::copy(iris)
  data.table::setDT(dt)

  iris_filtered = reactive({
    dt[Species == input$type]
  })

  output$scatter = renderPlot({
    plot(iris_filtered()$Petal.Width, 
       iris_filtered()$Petal.Length)
  })

}

# plotting module
iris_plotOutput = function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)

  plotOutput(ns("scatter"))
}

## call inputs in the sidebar
iris_plotUI("ns_iris")
```

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
## all server module and plot (plot in main panel) 
callModule(iris_plot, "ns_iris")
iris_plotOutput("ns_iris")
```
````

WRT to the naming conventions, this has been clarified in the blog post's comments. The message:

> It's a bit unclear to me, do the suffixes UI, Input, Output affect behavior or is that a suggested naming convention?

has been answered by one of the authors:

> Just a suggested naming convention, they don't affect anything.

Comment: Your working code is a shiny inline app. Do you want to split the broken code into a separate script and call it within flexdashboard?

Comment: Yes, preferably using the conventions laid out here:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html, i.e. a function for the UI and a function to call within some namespace for the server stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an `htmlwidget` instead of `rCharts` to get around the issue. Still unsure why `rCharts` wouldn't let me call the functions as stand-alone when `htmlwigdets` will, but as `htmlwidgets` seems to generalise `rCharts`, this closes the issue for me.

Comment: `rCharts` is no longer being actively developed.  We have discussed converting `rCharts` to leverage the helpful infrastructure that `htmlwidgets` provides.  Here is how it would look with rCharts dimple http://www.buildingwidgets.com/blog/2015/3/18/week-11-dimple-as-htmlwidget.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 small problems with your code:

#### 1. The naming of the module functions doesn't follow  [the documentation you are referring to](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)

> A module’s UI function should be given a name that is suffixed with
>   `Input`, `Output`, or `UI`

and

> Module server functions should be named like their corresponding
>   module UI functions, but without the `Input/Output/UI` suffix

Here I renamed them `myUI()` and `my()`:

```
myUI = function(id) {
        ns = NS(id)
        mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1", height = "100%"),
                  showOutput(ns("histogram"), "nvd3"))
}

my = function(input, output, session) {
        output$histogram <- renderChart2({
                n2 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Var1, group = 'Var2', data = X, type = 'multiBarChart')
                n2$set(width = session$clientData$output_plot1_width)
                n2
        })
}
```

#### 2. The way you call the the module server functions like if they were stand-alone

Instead they have to be called by `ui()` and `server()` which are themselves called by `shinyApp()`.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  myUI("example")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(my, "example")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi @HubertL, thanks for your reply. I've updated the question in response to your answer. In response to your two points, the naming convention is just as suggestion as mentioned in the blog post. Secondly, I'm trying to call the `ui` and `server` as stand-alone as they shouldn't need to be wrapped in `shinyApp` when using `flex` - an example of how this is done with normal plots has been added to the comments.